# Apache Directory Client Login Active Drectory never get the account locked

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap

I tried to login Active Directory with Apache Directory Client, and it works well.

However, when I tried to login Active Directory with incorrect password, it never locks the account no matter how many times.

For Active Directory server, it do will lock out my account if i tried wrong password 3 times with Windows 7 login screen.

Comment: What exactly is your question. How to make Apache Directory behave like Active Directory or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce. When I put 3 bad login from Apache Directory Studio (simple bind) my account get locked.

Comment: Thanks your answer, it could be the different setting on my Active Directory server, which is out of my control.

Comment: ShaMan-H, I just use Apache Directory API as a client, not Apache DS.